# How can I ensure two threads executing the same function to be mutually exclusive

Tags: c++, c, mutex

Two threads are going to use the same `func()`. The two threads should be mutually exclusive. How do I get it to work properly?

(Output should be "abcdeabcde")

```
char arr[] = "ABCDE";
int len = 5;

void func() {
    for(int i = 0; i <len;i++)
        printf("%c",arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: no!!!  its something that bother me

Comment: why not just `printf("%s", arr)`?

Comment: it does not matter what will be in the printf i just wanted to know if i can use an elementary code that will be thread safe

Comment: @Vlad: because your code requires that the array be nul-terminated, and the questioner's code doesn't? It's clearly just an example, you may as well say "why not get rid of arr and len entirely and just do `printf("ABCDE");` " ;-)

Comment: @Steve: AFAIK the string `"ABCDE"` **is** implicitly null-terminated. Using `printf(s)` instead of `printf("%s", s)` (even for a string constant `s`) is IMHO a bad style, since it silently assumes that `s` doesn't contain printf-specific control characters, which (1) may be not the case in the future, and (2) is not documented and therefore is easily overlooked by the developers.

Comment: @Vlad: the string "ABCDE" is, but an arbitrary pair `(arr, len)` isn't necessarily. So the questioner's loop is more general than your recommended replacement - it operates on an array (or pointer) and a length, rather than on a nul-terminated string. That's why I compared your suggestion with my own (hypothetical) suggestion which is less general again. And you're right, use `puts` with a string literal, not `printf`.

Comment: @Steve: in my case, function works on C-style string, which is a pretty popular usecase. Non-null-terminated C-strings are quite rare in the C++ world, right?

Comment: It's just an example of code which accesses a data structure. I think it's silly to argue what example "should" have been used, since *obviously* this isn't the real code, because `printf` doesn't require exclusive access in any implementation I can think of. I offered a difference between your code, and the code it replaced - if you want to argue that you have a better way of printing a nul-terminated string in C++, then (a) you're right, (b) your way is probably still not the best, (c) it's a completely different question from the one the questioner asked.

Answer (score 7):

Create a mutex? Assuming you're using pthread,

```
static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

....

void func() {
    int errcode = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    // deal with errcode...
    // printf...
    errcode = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    // deal with errcode...
}
```

See https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes for a tutorial.

Comment: can i do it with an elementary code??
like while or if??
or i must use special functions?

Comment: You have to use special instructions -- read about atomicity.

Comment: @nisnis: No, you must use special functions. Elementary code is not thread-aware (some languages have a special `synchronize`/`lock` block that functions as a mutex, but not `while` or `if`.)

Answer (score 1):

1. In the main thread, initialize mutex m.
2. In the main thread, create two threads that both start in some function x().
3. In x(), get mutex m.
4. In x(), Call func().
5. In x(), Release mutex m.

Answer (score 0):

Since you labeled this C++, you should know that C++11 includes standard library features specifically to handle locking.

[std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)
[std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex arr_mutex;
char arr[] = "ABCDE";
int len = 5;

void func() {
    // Scoped lock, which locks mutex and then releases lock at end of scope.
    // Classic RAII object.
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(arr_mutex);

    for(int i = 0; i <len;i++)
        printf("%c,arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: C++11 for something from 2010? ;-)